# React Native Maps - Callout don't show image inside

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a problem when I try to render an image inside the React Native Maps Callout.

The image does not render.

```js
{this.state.database.map((route, idx) => {
        if (route.Image) {
          return (
            <MapView.Marker
              coordinate={{ latitude: Number.parseFloat(route.Latitude), longitude: Number.parseFloat(route.Longitude) }}
              key={idx}
              image={img_pin}
              ref={(ref) => this.marker = ref}
            >
              <MapView.Callout tooltip style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Latitude: {route.Latitude}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Longitude: {route.Longitude}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Status: <Icon name={route.Status === 1 ? 'checkmark-circle' : 'close-circle'} style={{ color: route.Status === 1 ? 'green' : 'red', fontSize: 16 }} /> </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Velocidade: {route.Speed} km/h</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: `data:image/gif;base64,${route.Image}` }} style={{ width: 150, height: 100 }} />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </MapView.Callout>
            </MapView.Marker>
          );
        }
      })}
```

[Image error don't render inside Callout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqVtY.png)

```
"react-native": "^0.57.8",
"react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
```

Comment: Did you added support in build.gradle?

Comment: What support? Could you explain me better?

Answer (score 1):

Use Image inside Text component

```
<Text> <Image style={{ height: 100, width:100 }} source={{ ... }} resizeMode="cover" /> </Text>
```

Another workaround by using WebView. I think is the proper solution for this right now.

```
<View>
  <WebView style={{ height: 100 , width: 230, }} source={{ uri: ... }} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `route.image` is in the form of url schema,

exampleData

```
 source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}}
```

if correct,

> **GIF and WebP support on Android**

When building your own native code, **GIF** and **WebP** are not supported by default on Android.

You will need to add some optional modules in `android/app/build.gradle`, depending on the needs of your app.

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.10.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
}
```

Usage

```js
  <MapView.Callout tooltip={true} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: contentHeight, width: contentWidth }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Latitude: {route.Latitude}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Longitude: {route.Longitude}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Status: <Icon name={route.Status === 1 ? 'checkmark-circle' : 'close-circle'} style={{ color: route.Status === 1 ? 'green' : 'red', fontSize: 16 }} /> </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textCallout}>Velocidade: {route.Speed} km/h</Text>
                  </View>
                 <Image source={{ uri: `data:image/gif;base64,${route.Image}` }} style={{ width: 150, height: 100, resizeMode="cover" }} />
                </View>
              </MapView.Callout>
```

Comment: Yes... After follow your changes

Comment: It may be hard, but I updated my answer again. Would you like to run it?